# Call a Python script from a Applescript

Tags: python, macos, shell, applescript

My Applescript and Python script are in the present working directory.
Now I need to call the Python script named test.py with admin privileges from the applescript using shell commands.

**This code in Applescript gives the pwd**

```
tell application "Finder" to get folder of (path to me) as Unicode text
set presentDir to POSIX path of result
```

**This code in Applescript calls a python script from an Applescript manually**

```
do shell script "/Users/mymac/Documents/'Microsoft User Data'/test.py"
```

How to add the presentDir to this command along with Admin privileges?

EDIT and UPDATE:

```
set py to "test.py "
set calldir to workingDir & py
do shell script calldir
```

It gives an error

```
error "sh: /Users/mymac/Documents/Microsoft: No such file or directory" number 127
```

But 
 display dialog calldir
shows

```
/Users/mymac/Documents/Microsoft User Data/test.py
```

Reason:

it gets breaked up after the word 'Microsoft' in shell script command because of space.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you know the script is in the same directory, just use:

```
do shell script presentDir & "test.py " user name "me" password "mypassword" with administrator privileges
```

Notice the space after `test.py` before the close-quote. You may possibly need the string to be `/test.py`, rather than `test.py`, I'm not sure.

I got this info from http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2065/_index.html.

Edit: Try

```
set py to "test.py "
set calldir to quoted form of workingDir & py
do shell script calldir
```

Comment: since test.py is in the same directory of presentDir, How can I ignore the usage of "/users/mymac/Documents/'Microsoft User Data'/test.py "in the shell script command.

Comment: Im not sure I understand your question, but I edited with my best guess for what you mean?

Comment: To quote `var` use `quoted form of var`.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial script didn't work because you didn't escape the spaces with a backslash "\" as such:
"/Users/mymac/Documents/Microsoft\ User\ Data/test.py"